# How would I change the color of one word in the button?

Tags: html, css

How would I change the color of one word in the button?

I've tried using `<input type="submit" value="lool <span style='color: red'>lool2</span">` but it just shows the code instead.

Comment: Your code isn't working because you've put the span inside the input tag.

Comment: An `<input />` element *cannot contain any child elements*, to do as you want you have no choice but to use a `<button>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a `span` and give the span a specific color.

HTML:

```
<button type="button">
    <span class="color">Click</span>Me!
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.color{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you have more than one word in the button, you will have to use a span element. Otherwise, there's no way to discriminate between what you do want coloured and what you don't.

Comment: @LucyBrockleworth I don't know if it is possible what you are trying to achieve. I've googled it and cannot find anything.

Comment: According to the OP's posted snippet it's better to use `type="submit"` instead.

Comment: I mean input, not button!

Comment: I know what you mean, using input instead of button. But I couldn't find an answer for that.

Comment: @LucyBrockleworth What's the reason of using `<input>` button? What's wrong with `<button>`?

Comment: This answer fails to say the essential thing explicitly: you need to use `button`, not `input`. Technically, it does not answer at all the question how to color just one word in an `input type=submit` button. (The correct answer to that is “You can’t”.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<button>One<span style="color: red">Two</span></button>
```